# How to set css property that are inside a tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can set all property in my entire html using:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.setProperty(--color-dustomized, "red");
```

But I just wanted to change the tags that are INSIDE the div with id class2, I tried something like this, but the error appears `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'`

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getElementsByClassName('class2')[0].style.setProperty(--color-dustomized, "red"); // Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

I can't use it this way as I don't know how many `div` will be on the page:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[1]
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getElementsByClassName('class2')[0].style.setProperty(--color-dustomized, "red");
```

```html
<div id="class1" class="class1">
  <!-- code -->
</div>

<div id="class2" class="class2">
  <!-- code -->
</div>
```

Comment: In your message you say that you want to select the div with `id="class2"` but in your code you are selecting class `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getElementsByClassName('class2')` change it with `getElementsById`

Comment: with getElementsByTagName the same error occurs `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'`

Comment: And for what element you do have set the style property?

Comment: If you don't know how many there are, get all of them and then use a loop.

Comment: Give them all a common class so you can use `getElementsByClassName()` to find them all at once.

Comment: Btw., `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getElementsByClassName()` is pretty pointless. You might as well call `document.getElementsByClassName()` instead, because the difference between selecting from all elements in the whole document, and selecting among descendants of `html`, is minimal - would only be relevant if the `html` element itself had the class you are looking for. (And even if that wasn't the case, `document.documentElement` is a more concise way to access the HTML element, of which there can be only one to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
`document.getElementById("class1").style.color="red";`
```

Comment: i need add one property, example:  `setProperty(--color-dustomized, "red");`  the --color-dustomized exists in my css

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("class1").style["--color-dustomized"] = "red"
```

Answer (score 0):

just type this:

```
document.getElementById("class1").style.setProperty("--color-dustomized","red");
```